# AngularJS test - inject $location causes error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

So this one is driving me crazy, whenever i try to inject `$location` to one of my tests i get the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at $LocationProvider.$get (bower_components/angular/angular.js:11053:34)
    at Object.invoke (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4118:17)
    at bower_components/angular/angular.js:3936:37
    at getService (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4077:39)
    at Object.invoke (bower_components/angular/angular.js:4109:13)
    at Object.workFn (bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2159:20)
Error: Declaration Location
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2144:25)
    at Suite.<anonymous> (test/unit/controllers/DashboardCtrlSpec.js:8:16)
    at jasmineInterface.describe (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js:59:18)
    at test/unit/controllers/DashboardCtrlSpec.js:1:1
```

karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '../',


        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],


        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js',
            'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
            'bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js',
            'bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js',
            'bower_components/dist/assets.angular.max.js',
            'scripts/**/*.js',
            'test/**/*.js'
        ],


        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [
            '**/*.swp'
        ],


        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {},


        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ['progress'],


        // web server port
        port: 9876,


        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,


        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: false,


        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: true
    });
};
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('ecQDesktopApp')
    .controller('DashboardCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {

        $scope.goToURL = function (url) {
            $window.location = url;
        }

    }
);
```

Functioning Spec file:

```
describe('Unit: Testing Dashboard Controller', function() {
    'use strict';

    var scope, window;

    beforeEach(module('ecQDesktopApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _$window_, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        window = {
            location: ""
        };
        $controller('DashboardCtrl', {$scope: scope, $window: window});
    }));

    it('goes to Url', function() {
        var url = "testUrl";
        scope.goToURL(url);
        expect(window.location).toBe("testUrl");
    });
});
```

But if i change `beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _$window_, $controller)` to  `beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _$window_, $controller, $location)` i get the error.

It's weird, it looks like i can inject any AngularJS services but whenever i try to use $location in any of my tests i get that crash.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to pass it to the `$controller` function.

Comment: Well this was just an example using a controller, i actually found the bug while trying to test a directive. It just bothered me that $location is the only one i can't inject (for example i can inject $templateCache, $templateRequest or $timeout and it does not crash)

Comment: the `inject` line is throwing the error?

Comment: you have the error stack on the post, it's the first code box. this `at Suite.<anonymous> (test/unit/controllers/DashboardCtrlSpec.js:8:16)` is the line of the inject

Answer (score 5):

If you are using angular in a version >= 1.3, you have also to use angular-mocks in a version >= 1.3

In general:
The version of angular-mocks should always be at the same level as angular.

Comment: What makes you think the error comes from this please?

Comment: We've updated to version 1.3 without changing the code base. Thereafter, the same error occurred as in the question. As we had updated angular-mocks the error disappeared.

Comment: Had `angular-mocks#1.2.x` and `angular#1.3.13` and started getting this error as soon as I needed to inject `$location` in my tests. After upgrading to `angular-mocks#1.3.13`, error went away.